# Pronunciation of a double C

Tags: pronunciation, doubled-consonants

I always pronounce words like "accelerate" and "eccentric" as "asselerate" or "eesentric". I don't know why but the "ks" that I hear in common pronunciation irks me. Is it correct to pronounce the c's as "ss" instead? I have heard once or twice the aforementioned pronunciation of "eccentric", but never of "accelerate".

Comment: To pronounce as "ss" would be essentric.

Comment: What pronunciation has your dictionary or OALD online?

Comment: A _c_ is pronounced as a _k_ before consonants, so why would pronouncing a _c_ before a _c_ "irk" you? English pronunciation can be a mess, but in this case, it is very consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course pronounce these '-cc-' words however you like; but in most (or all) places where English is spoken, the *standard* pronunciation uses 'ks' (or 'x', if you prefer).

Here are links to Cambridge Dictionaries' entries for [accelerate](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/british/accelerate) and [eccentricity](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/british/eccentricity); both the UK and US pronunciation clips use 'ks' for both words.

That being said, I have certainly heard the 'ss' pronunciation being used with *accelerate, eccentric* and *accessory,* so your pronunciation preference does not put you completely out on a limb.

Comment: I've only heard that pronunciation used by speakers of AAVE and some of the more extreme Southern US dialects—and the same speakers also had thighs like ‘essit’ for _exit_, ‘he eass’ for _he eats_, ‘when he poss his closs’ for _when he pops his clogs_, so they just reduce more or less any cluster with a final sibilant to a geminate sibilant. The only word I know where orthographic _-cc-_ commonly reflects [s] as well as [ks] is _flaccid_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'm still trying to picture those deliciously sibilant thighs...

Comment: Hah! The wonders of auto-correct sneaking up on you!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - There's one more word I can think of that follows the pattern of *flaccid.* This is *succinct*, where it seems to me that both the 'ss' and 'ks' pronunciations coexist on a more or less equal footing.

Comment: I don’t think I’ve ever come across an [s] pronunciation in that word, but the dictionary does give [sə(k)sɪŋ(k)t], so it would appear it is common enough there, too. (Conversely, the dictionary gives [flæ(k)sɪd] for _flaccid_, but there I can’t recall ever hearing anyone use the [ks] pronunciation.)